# Android: Run app in emulator without Google Maps installed

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Is it possible to install and debug an app in the emulator that requires Google Maps for Android 4.0 or higher? I noticed that Maps is not included with the SDK, other than the API. If it's not possible, how does one test an app in the emulator that requires Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. To to that you have to create you project using the Google API 14 or higher, instead of using the standard Android API 14 or higher. If you're not installed the Google API, then you have to download and install the required Google API version using the SDK Manager, in this case Google API version 14 or higher. In any case if the SDK Manager doesn't show the Google APIs, then you have to update the ADT Plugins and SDK Manager to the latest.

Comment: If I create my project with Google API 14, then that means that it will only run on a device using API 14. Yet I would also like it to run on API 5. Are you suggesting that I only use API 14 for testing in the emulator but when I can then switch it back to API 5 for the release version? Also, does the API actually show a map in the app even if Google Maps is not installed?

Comment: I would say if you're not using any new features in API 14, then you don't have to use API 14 or higher at all, even to do testing in emulator. Instead you can use API 5. If so, you have to download, install and use Google API level 5. If you use any new features in API level 14, then you can't switch back to API level 5 when you're done creating your app.



You don't have to install Official Google Maps app to show Google maps inside your android app.